# change input field value via javascript in grails

Tags: javascript, grails

In my Grails project I have a field that allows me to select between a list.

After user has selected a value, I store the id of the related object.

I would like that, after storing the id, I get a value related to the object with that id and show it into another input field.

Here is the javascript that I use to store the id:

```
$("#patient_textField").autocomplete({
       source: data,
       select: function (event, ui){                                

                $('#patient_id').val(ui.item.id);                        

                }
            });
```

I've created a function in controller that allows me to get the value that I need to show into the second input field

```
def getPhoneNumberFromPatientId(int patientID)
{
    int phone = Patient.findById(patientID).phone_1
    if(phone == null)
        phone = Patient.findById(patientID).phone_2

    return phone
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please, see the answer below, since it can help you to achieve what you want. You don't need to use GSP templates for that, but all elements, as g:remoteFunction and how you can update an HTML element through an AJAX call can be viewed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717501/grails-updating-values-in-form-using-ajax/30721528#30721528

Comment: Thanks... but I do not understand how to set the value inside the input field...how the update in remote-function works?I've tried to use the onSuccess but I do not know how to pass a parameter to the function called inside onSuccess (the parameter is the render of controller function)

Comment: Ok. I'm writing an example. As soon as possible I post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AJAX to accomplish what you want. In Grails you have some taglibs that are very useful to execute an AJAX call.

An example is g:remoteFunction. This taglib allows you to execute an AJAX call and update the content of an HTML element. It's a very useful taglib!

For this question I've wrote an example that allows the user to select an option in a list (HTML Select) and update the content of a textArea based on the user selection. The update is performed by an AJAX call.

**Main GSP (test.gsp)**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>    
    <label>Select an option: </label>
    <g:select name="cbOption" noSelection="['':'']" from="${options}"  onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'getPhoneNumberFromPatientId', onSuccess: '\$("#value").val(data)', params:'\'patientId=\' + escape(this.value)')}; \$('#value').focus()"></g:select>
    <g:textArea name="value"></g:textArea>
</body>
</html>
```

The AJAX call happens in the onchange event of g:select. For simplicity I omit some attributes of g:select as optionValue and optionKey.

This GSP is rendered by the following action:

```
def test() {
   def options = ["A","B","C"]
   return [options:options]
}
```

As you can see, this action **returns** an model to the above GSP that must be called test.gsp since this is name of the action. The variable options is the list of elements that could be selected by the user.

**Remote Function**

The remote function calls an action called getPhoneNumberFromPatientId and on the onSuccess event updates the textArea called **value**. The update is performed using JQuery.

```
${remoteFunction(action: 'getPhoneNumberFromPatientId', onSuccess: '\$("#value").val(data)', params:'\'patientId=\' + escape(this.value)')}
```

See below the action getPhoneNumberFromPatientId:

```
def getPhoneNumberFromPatientId(String patientId) {
  def phone

  if (patientId == "A")
    phone = "3332-2222"

  else if (patientId == "B")
    phone = "4444-2222"

  else if (patientId == "C")
    phone = "5555-2222"

  render phone
}
```

The actions above doesn't return, the actions render the content. It's a very importante difference. See this answer to understand the difference: [Grails updating values in form using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717501/grails-updating-values-in-form-using-ajax?lq=1)

Basically when you're working with AJAX call you'll render the content. The content could be a variable (as above), an HTML snippet or a GSP template.

Please, check the source code of your page (in your browser) to understand that your g:remoteFunction was rendered as a JQuery AJAX call.

**Bonus**

After the AJAX call I set the focus on the textArea. This is done using JQuery too. See the end of the onchange event to understand this part.